# ScadaLTS application does not start

Tags: scadalts

The ScadaLTS application is not starting, I am getting the following errors:

[image: error screeshot]

Comment: I'll check it. The plan is to prepare the docker.

Comment: You may get docker https://hub.docker.com/r/dockergb/scadalts/ and run "docker run -it dockergb/scadalts /root/start.sh"